# Finding StartDate,EndDate from overriding StartDates

Tags: sql, join, date-range

I have two tables with the following (simplified) structures:

1. table "Factors" which holds data about purchased goods' factors and has these columns:

   FactorSerial, PurchaseDate, PurchasedGood
2. table "Prices" which holds goods prices on different dates

   Serial, GoodCode, EvaluationDate, Price

A price is valid until a new row with the same Code but different date is added and thus updates its value

Now, I want to create a table which adds the price to the table 1 according to purchase date.
So if we have:

```
  PurchaseDate  PurchasedGood
 -----------------------------
  05/20/2011      A111
```

and:

```
  GoodCode  EvaluationDate  Price
 --------------------------------
   A111      02/01/2011     100
...
   A111      04/01/2011     110
...
   A111      06/01/2011     120
```

the result would be

```
  PurchaseDate  PurchasedGood  Price
 -----------------------------------
  05/20/2011      A111          110
```

Preferred method is creating the view Prices1 as

```
 Serial  GoodCode   StartDate  EndDate  Price
```

and then joining Factors with this view by

```
  PurchasedDate between StartDate AND EndDate
```

Can anybody show me how to create view1 (or obtaining the final result with any other method)? Thanks in advance!

P.S. sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create a table which adds the price to the table 1 according to purchase date.

Here is a query that returns such data. The syntax is pretty standard SQL, I believe, but this was tested on SQL Server (looks like you may be using PostgreSQL with your "serial" naming).

```
select a.FactorSerial, a.PurchasedGood, a.PurchaseDate
    , (select max(Price) from Prices where GoodCode = a.PurchasedGood and EvaluationDate = a.EvaluationDate) as Price
from (
    select f.FactorSerial, f.PurchasedGood, f.PurchaseDate, max(p.EvaluationDate) as EvaluationDate
    from Factors as f
        join Prices as p on f.PurchasedGood = p.GoodCode
    where f.PurchaseDate >= p.EvaluationDate
    group by f.FactorSerial, f.PurchasedGood, f.PurchaseDate
) as a
```

This query assumes that there are no Purchases before a Price existed.

Also, considering:

> Preferred method is creating the view Prices1 as
>
> ```
> Serial  GoodCode   StartDate  EndDate  Price
> ```
>
> and then joining Factors with this view by
>
> ```
>  PurchasedDate between StartDate AND EndDate
> ```

`between` is inclusive.  Using this method that you've described, you would get duplicates if a `PurchaseDate` lies on the `EndDate` of one row and the `StartDate` of another.